# Spring's aspectj-autoproxy conflict with Enum factory-method

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have an enum

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    AAA, BBB;
    public static final MyEnum findByName(String theName)
    {
        return MyEnum.valueOf(theName.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

And I instantiate it as:

```
<bean id="myEnum" class="xxx.MyEnum" factory-method="findByName">
    <constructor-arg value="${someProperties}" />
</bean>
```

And can inject it easily in other class:

```
@Autowired(required = true)
@Qualifier("myEnum")
private MyEnum test;
```

But I need to use proxy for logging things.  When I put this to my app context xml:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

The app context would not load, I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [xxx.MyEnum] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=myEnum)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 82 more
```

Comment: Is that your actual Enum or is your actual  enum by any change implementing an interface.

Comment: That is my actual enum, no interface

Comment: Add `proxy-target-class="true"` to your `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` or fix your logging aspect to not match the enum.

Comment: You are right, I did not notice that I had my enum under the package of classes I wish to pointcut.  This solves my problem, thank you